# What is the correct way of writing: else if (9<result<16) in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

the syntax:

```
(9<result<16)
```

is appearing to be invalid when I'm using it in my C# code. I want the else if statement to consider the condition: when the sum of two integers is greater than 9 and less than 16, and return the line :"That's a poor grade" as a result. But the problem is that writing the condition as (9

[Screen shot of code to give you context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tfHZ.png)

Edit: ignore the following as I'm writing all this to make the edit more substantive, so that my post can be corrected

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code

Comment: `if (9 < result && result < 16)`

Comment: Okay, but why not? I would just like to know. @Knoop

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10608418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to

```
else if (9 < result && result < 16)
```

Also, you need return int value in `Add` method as

```
public static int Add (int num01, int num02){
   //Console if need
   return num01 + num02;

}
```

Comment: will it work okay? because I need an 'else if' statement there, not an if.

Comment: yes, i updated answer

Comment: Ok, that seems to be fine now but can you help me with one other thing? If you look at the image i've attached, go down to ```public static int Add```. There is a red line under Add and when I hover the mouse over it it says 'not all code paths return a value'. Why is that? What is still wrong in the code?

Comment: I updated answer, you need return value for add method